# proof of a vector identity

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

In an exercise I am asked to prove the following vector identity: $$\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{b}=\frac{1}{4}\big(|\textbf{a}+\textbf{b}|^{2}-|\textbf{a}-\textbf{b}|^{2}\big)$$

Both the dimension of the vector space and the field over which the vector space is defined are not given in the exercise, so I assumed a general case $\textbf{a},\textbf{b}\in\mathbb{F}^{n}$, then 
$$|\textbf{a}+\textbf{b}|^{2}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (a_{i}+b_{i})(\overline{a_{i}+b_{i}})$$
and similarly
$$|\textbf{a}-\textbf{b}|^{2}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (a_{i}-b_{i})(\overline{a_{i}-b_{i}})$$
by extending the sums and computing $|\textbf{a}+\textbf{b}|^{2}-|\textbf{a}-\textbf{b}|^{2}$ we obtain \begin{align}2(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{i}\overline{b_{i}}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_{i}\overline{a_{i}})=2(\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{b}+\textbf{b}\cdot\textbf{a})\end{align}
So is it correct to conclude that the identity always holds for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ but does not always hold for $\mathbb{F}^{n}$? Since for vectors defined over $\mathbb{F}$ in general $\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{b}\neq\textbf{b}\cdot\textbf{a}$

Comment: As far as I see it, we *always* have $\;\Bbb F=\Bbb R\;\;or\;\;\Bbb C\;$ , as we have an inner product here. About the finite dimensional thing: it depends what you're dealing with in class. At the beginning it is usually finite dimensional stuff. BTW, also or $\;\Bbb F=\Bbb C\;$  we have in the general case that $\;a\cdot b\neq b\cdot a\;$

Comment: This is a good observation. For real vector spaces, this is true. For complex, a different equality holds (which involves $i$). See the polarization identity here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you! this answered my question.

Comment: Since [fields are commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Definition_and_illustration), [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Properties) is commutative. So the identity does hold for all fields. Unless you define fields or dot product differently, of course.